# How can I find maximums of a function without Table and FindPeaks?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following equation

$$\pi_{xx} = \exp(-2 k_x^2 \sin^2(\frac{t}{2})) k_x^2 \theta(t) 
         \times \bigg[ -\frac{\sin(2t)}{2} - \cos(t) \sin(t) (1 - k_x^2 \sin^2(\frac{t}{2})) 
        + 2 \cos(t) \sin^2(\frac{t}{2}) \sin^2(t) + 2 \sin^2(t) 
         - 4 k_x^2 \sin^2(t) \sin^2(\frac{t}{2}) - 2 \sin(2t) \cos(t) \sin^2(t) 
         - \sin(2t) \sin^2(t) + 2 k_x^2 \sin(2t) \sin^2(t) \sin^2(\frac{t}{2})\bigg]$$

[image]

I want to find maximums of this function (points where the time derivative is zero). The goal here is to have a comparison with my code result, so it should be accurate. Using `Table` or `FindPeaks` will not be accurate enough. The proper way is to use `D` to compute the time derivative, and `FindRoots` to find the maximum values.

`k` here is the wave number. It could be `{10, 20, 30, 40, ...}`.

What I tried so far is as follows.

```
xxrot = E^(-2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2)k^2 Cos[0.4292036732051034 + t]^2 (-Sin[t] (1 - k^2 Sin[t]^2) - Sin[2 t]) + E^(-2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2) k^2 (-4 Sin[t/2]^2 Sin[t] - (1 - 4 k^2 Sin[t/2]^4) Sin[t]) Sin[0.4292036732051034 + t]^2 - E^(-2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2)k^2 (2 Cos[t] Sin[t/2]^2 + Sin[t]^2 - 2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2 Sin[t]^2) Sin[2 (0.4292036732051034 + t)]; 
    
xxrotplt = Plot[xxrot /. k -> -i2k@20 /. t -> t - 2 // Evaluate, {t, 0, 2000 0.01}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red];
    
i2k[i_] = 1/2 (i - 1) ;
    
pl = xxrot /. k -> -i2k[80] /. t -> t - 200*0.01;
tab = Table[pl, {t, 8.1, 8.3, 0.01}];
pp = Rest@FindPeaks[tab];
plta = ListLinePlot[tab, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point /@ pp}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All]
pts = Cases[plta, 
   Point[{x_, y_ /; y > 20}] :> {x/100, y}, \[Infinity]] // Sort
```

Here the wave number is 80, and the result of the above code is
[image]

You can see how bad it is for high wave numbers and it is not possible to compare this result with the code result.

However, when I used  `D` and `FindRoots` it got more complicated (it is not helpful to put my try here).

I appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Unclear: Are you looking for "points where the time derivative is zero" or global maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your function written out as a fuction of t and k:

```mathematica
xxrot[t_, k_] := 
  E^(-2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2) k^2 Cos[
      0.4292036732051034 + t]^2 (-Sin[t] (1 - k^2 Sin[t]^2) - 
      Sin[2 t]) + 
   E^(-2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2) k^2 (-4 Sin[t/2]^2 Sin[
        t] - (1 - 4 k^2 Sin[t/2]^4) Sin[t]) Sin[
      0.4292036732051034 + t]^2 - 
   E^(-2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2) k^2 (2 Cos[t] Sin[t/2]^2 + Sin[t]^2 - 
      2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2 Sin[t]^2) Sin[2 (0.4292036732051034 + t)];
```

If you plot it, you'll see if matches your plot above:

```
Plot[xxrot[t, 10], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Take the derivative:

```
dxx[t_] := D[xxrot[t, 10], t]
```

Now use FindRoot to find values near the peaks:

```
FindRoot[dxx[t], {t, #}] & /@ {Range[5, 6.5, 0.01]}
```

This gives out a collection of answers, some of which have failed. But among them you will find

```
t-> 6.207973968942875`
```

for which

```
xxrot[6.207973968942875`, 10]

(* 12.4548 *)
```

is the largest peak in the region. So I would just search through the returned values to find the largest.

Comment: Thanks bill. 

However, how can I know which t is the right one? your code produces many answers. How can I quickly find the correct one among them?

Comment: And actually, what is the reason of having many answers?

Comment: If you evaluate xxrot at all the candidate answers, one of them will be the largest... this is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

xxrot[t_, k_] := 
  E^(-2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2) k^2 Cos[
       0.4292036732051034 + t]^2 (-Sin[t] (1 - k^2 Sin[t]^2) - 
       Sin[2 t]) + 
    E^(-2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2) k^2 (-4 Sin[t/2]^2 Sin[
         t] - (1 - 4 k^2 Sin[t/2]^4) Sin[t]) Sin[
       0.4292036732051034 + t]^2 - 
    E^(-2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2) k^2 (2 Cos[t] Sin[t/2]^2 + Sin[t]^2 - 
       2 k^2 Sin[t/2]^2 Sin[t]^2) Sin[2 (0.4292036732051034 + t)] // 
   Rationalize[#, 0] &;

sol = Table[{k, 
   Maximize[{xxrot[t, k], 0 <= t <= 20}, t] // N[#, 50] & // N}, 
   {k, 10, 80, 10}]

(* {{10, {12.4548, {t -> 18.7743}}}, {20, {24.848, {t -> 
     18.8119}}}, {30, {37.2395, {t -> 18.8244}}}, {40, {49.6305, {t ->
      18.8307}}}, {50, {62.0213, {t -> 18.8345}}}, {60, {74.412, {t ->
      18.837}}}, {70, {86.8026, {t -> 18.8388}}}, {80, {99.1932, {t ->
      18.8401}}}} *)

Plot[xxrot[t, 80], {t, 187/10, 19},
 WorkingPrecision -> 50,
 PlotRange -> All,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{t, xxrot[t, 80]}] /. sol[[-1, -1, -1]]}]
```

[image]

**EDT:** For each of the wave numbers,

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  xxrot[t, #] & /@ Range[10, 80, 10]],
 {t, 1874/100, 1886/100},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> {-30, All},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[({t, xxrot[t, #[[1]]]} /. #[[2, 2, -1]]) & /@
     sol]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[
    Range[10, 80, 10],
    LegendLabel -> Style["k", 14],
    LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}],
   {.3, .7}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** To find all of the maxima for each wave number

The first derivative w.r.t. t is

```
der[t_, k_] = D[xxrot[t, k], t] //
   FullSimplify[#, k > 0 && t >= 0] &;
```

The second derivative w.r.t. t is

```
der2[t_, k_] = D[der[t, k], t] //
   FullSimplify[#, k > 0 && t >= 0] &;
```

The maxima occur at

```
Column[(sol2 = Table[{k, Solve[
      {der[t, k] == 0, der2[t, k] < 0, 0 <= t <= 20},
      t, Reals]},
    {k, 10, 80, 10}]) /. x_Root :> N[N[x, 50]]]
```

[image]

Plotting,

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[xxrot[t, k], {t, 0, 20},
  WorkingPrecision -> 50,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  MaxRecursion -> 7,
  PlotRange -> {-5, All},
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
    Point[{t, xxrot[t, k]} /. sol2[[k/10, 2]]]}],
 {{k, 10}, Range[10, 80, 10], 
    ControlType -> RadioButtonBar},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {k}]
```

[image]